# Wrapping text in tables

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabu, tabulary

I have looked at previous queries of similar issues but the solutions don't seem to work for me (I am very new to LaTex so this is probably just me!)

I am making a table which I want to fit within the page width of my document. I have tried tabularx and tabulary (using \textwidth or \linewidth)but this seems to only make the lines of the table the correct width with the text still running off. Any solutions will be great!

This is the current code with no formatting trying to fix the width issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
This is a line of text to show the line width to ensure the table is the correct width on the page
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Error in Gilson Autopipettes} \\
\hline
Autopipette & Max. Volume ($\mu$ L) & Sytematic Error ($\mu$ L) & Random Error ($\mu$ L) & Max. Error ($\mu$ L) \\
\hline
P10 & 10 & $\pm$ 0.100 & $\leq$ 0.040 &  \\
P200 & 200 & $\pm$ 1.60 & $\leq$ 0.30 &  \\
P1000 & 1000 & $\pm$ 8 & $\leq$ 1.5 &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you use `X` columns in combination with `tabularx` or `C` cells in combination with `tabulary`? The width of these sorts of columns is calculated in a way that the table fits the specified width and content is automatically wrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

[image]

- for `tabularx` you can prescribe table width, however, than you need to use at least one column type `X` (or derivative from it) in table. otherwise, table will have width of cell contents
- for writing numbers in columns i suggest to use `S` columns from `siunitx` package. using it the numbers are aligned at decimal point or right side, if numbers are intefgers
- for units also use `siunitx` package (see *mwe* below)
- for writing
- for professional looking of table don't use vertical lines, for horisontal use rules defined by `booktabs` package
- added package `lipsum` is for dummy text, in real document you should remove it, the same is valid for `showframe`, which purpose is show page layout (red lines on above image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%


\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X S >{\pm}S >{\pm}S S}
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{Error in Gilson Autopipettes}    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
\mcx{Autopipette}
    &   \mcx{Max. Volume (\si{\micro\liter})}
        &   \mcx{Sytematic Error (\si{\micro\liter})}
            &   \mcx{Random Error (\si{\micro\liter})}
                &   \mcx{Max. Error (\si{\micro\liter})}    \\
    \midrule
P10     &   10      &   0.100   &   0.040  &                \\
P200    &   200     &   1.60    &   0.30   &                \\
P1000   &   1000    &   8       &   1.5    &                \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**

for shorter code you can define new commands, similarly as it is defined for `\multicolumn` in above *mwe*, for units `\micro\liter` (as suggested [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) in his comment below:

in preamble, after `\usepackage{siunitx}`: `\newcomand{\ul}{\micro\liter}`

and use in table:

```
\mcx{Autopipette}
    &   \mcx{Max. Volume (\si{\uL})}
        &   \mcx{Sytematic Error (\si{\uL})}
            &   \mcx{Random Error (\si{\uL})}
                &   \mcx{Max. Error (\si{\uL})}    \\
```

Comment: I suggest slightly shorten the code, using the abbreviation `\uL` in  the place of `\micro\liter`.

Comment: good idea :-), i will add this to answer asap! thank you

Comment: Thank you so much! Slowly getting my head around all of this, your help is invaluable:)